# Cannot retrieve install parameters with Context.Parameters

Tags: c#, service

I'm attempting to retrieve a command line parameter when installing a service, using the following in the command prompt

```
installutil.exe myservice.exe /myvar=1
```

However, I can't seem to retrieve it using Context.Parameters["myvar"]. I've tried calling it in my override for OnBeforeInstall(), Install(), and OnAfterInstall(), with no results. When I use the following code:

```
foreach (string this_param in this.Context.Parameters.Keys)
{
   param_string += this_param + " " + this.Context.Parameters[this_param] + " ";
}
```

I only get the parameters logtoconsole, logfile, and assemblypath. It doesn't show myvar at all. I get the same result when dropping "this" from Context.Parameters. What did I miss or do wrong when attempting to retrieve this install option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/installutil-exe-installer-tool) suggests that variables should be provided **prior** to the exe name.

Therefore:

```
installutil.exe /myvar=1 myservice.exe
```